# How to register custom commands in webdriverIO using Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, webdriver-io

I had in `commands.js` file something like this:

```
module.exports = {
browserCustomCommandExample: function (text) {
        console.log(text);
  }
}
```

And in `wdio.conf.js` file something like this:

```
const commands = require('./src/commands/commands');

exports.config = {
...
before: function before() {

    Object.keys(commands).forEach(key => {
        browser.addCommand(key, commands[key]);
    });
}
...
}
```

How can I have the same principal or at least similar one if I wanted to have my commands written using Typescript in `commands.ts` file and use them somehow in `wdio.conf.js` to register the custom commands.
I am using webdriverIOv6 and Typescript 3.6.3.

Comment: Rename the file to `.ts` and compile it as `tsc --module commonjs --target es2015 ./command.ts`. The point is that you do not rewrite your code to when you add TypeScript. You will do little things like probably annotate `text` as `text: string`.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Ok, I just renamed the file to `command.ts`, but how do I import it to `wdio.conf.js` file? If I do `const commands = require('./src/config/commands');` then when running my tests I get `Error: Cannot find module './src/config/commands'`

Comment: Just a note, my `commands.ts` is located in `./src/config`folder

Answer (score 1):

There is an explanation of how to do it in the official docs, see https://webdriver.io/docs/typescript.html#adding-custom-commands